# Can angularjs routes have default parameter values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, url-routing

Can I set a default value of a parameter of a route in AngularJS? Is there a way to have `/products/123` and `/products/` handled by the same route ?

I'm looking to refactor my existing code, which looks like:

```
myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
     when('/products/', {templateUrl: 'products.html', controller: ProductsCtrl}).            
     when('/products/:productId', {templateUrl: 'products.html', controller: ProductsCtrl})
}]);


function ProductsCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.productId = typeof($routeParams.productId) == "undefined" ? 123 : $routeParams.productId;
}
```

It works, but it's not very elegant. Is there a better way ?

Comment: Not familiar with angularJS, but what about `var param ={templateUrl: 'products.html', controller: ProductsCtrl}; $routeProvider.when('/products/', param).when('/products/:productId', param)`?

Comment: You can simplify your controller code a bit with: $scope.productId = $routeParams.productId || 123;

Comment: @Gloopy this of course works if productId == 0 is not a valid id

Comment: Thanks guys, that does make it a bit shorter. Just the issue of whether default parameters are possible to go... ;)

Comment: Do not forget `ProductsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];`.

Comment: `$scope.productId = $routeParams.productId || 123;` should work

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`AngularJS` does not allow default values for route parameters.

But routes (in `AngularJS`) **should not have default parameters.**

Resources could have default parameters.

In `AngularJS` if you want a route with an optional parameter, these are actually two different routes.

**Why?**

- Routes should be simple
- Routes does not allow regular expressions matching for parameters
- Routes are not something which exposes an API to work in your application (unlike Resources do). Routes are just configuration which connects a URL with a template and a controller. Thus having more routes is better:

  - It is clear which route maps to which url.
  - It is more verbose, but simpler to read. Having more complex routes would create a steeper learning curve where AngularJS does not need one.

Unlike server-side frameworks which have routes

- AngularJS routes do not have names.
- You do not build URLs from the defined routes.
- You do not have logic (a.k.a functions) in the routes definitions.

Simpler routes = more lines to define them = less headaches working with them.

**NOTE**: Please keep in mind the question and this answer are for an old version of AngularJS (1.0 I think) pre-dating the new routes/resources implementation.

Comment: Though this may be the correct answer I don't see any strong argument here that should prevent AngularJS from having default params or better route matching. Repeating identical code is always a problem for maintenance.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y My point is that in the current state of AngularJS routes (which is probably going to change) routes should be kept simple.

Comment: Though this conversation is a bit dated I have heard that in the Angular 2 release there will be support for pattern matching for routes, this may also include some way to do optional or defaulted parameters.

Comment: @shaunhusain yes, this is most probably going to change. But the new AngularJS routes and all change a lot of the pre-conditions for the question and the answer.

Comment: Optional routes are now available right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510962/can-angularjs-routes-have-optional-parameter-values

Comment: I've updated my answer to let future readers know this is not about the current AngularJS version.

Answer (score 35):

I recognize that this question is old, but still: Why don't you just redirect the "empty" URL to one containing the default productId?

```
myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
     when('/products/', {redirectTo: '/products/123'}).
     when('/products/:productId', {templateUrl: 'products.html', controller: ProductsCtrl})
}]);
```

Comment: Method Overloading FTW!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar requirement. What i did was to create a function to resolve. Something like below

```
myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
 when('/products/', resolveProduct()).            
 when('/products/:productId', resolveProduct())
}]);


function ProductsCtrl($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.productId = $routeParams.productId;
}

function resolveProduct() {
   var routeConfig = {
      templateUrl: 'products.html', 
      controller: ProductsCtrl,
      resolve: {
         productId: ['$route', function($route){
            var params = $route.current.params;
            params.productId =  params.productId || 123;
         }]
      }
   }

   return routeConfig;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With **url: "/view/:id/:status?"**, You can indicate an optional parameter.

Just thought someone may need it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question is specific to `$routeProvider` but in [$stateProvider](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), you can achieve this by

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('products', {
            url: '/:productId',
            templateUrl: "/dashboard/products.html",
            controller: 'ProductController',
            params: {
                productId: {
                  value: "defaultValue",
                  squash: true // or enable this instead to squash `productId` when empty
                } 
            }
        });
});
```