# Can angularjs routes have optional parameter values?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Can I set a route with optional params (same template and controller, but some params should be ignored if they don't exist?

So instead of writing the following two rules, have only one?

```
module.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
     when('/users/', {templateUrl: 'template.tpl.html', controller: myCtrl}).            
     when('/users/:userId', {templateUrl: 'template.tpl.html', controller: myCtrl})
}]);
```

Something like this ([this param is optional])

```
when('/users[/:userId]', {templateUrl: 'template.tpl.html', controller: myCtrl})
//note: this previous doesn't work
```

I couldn't find anything in their documentation.

Comment: they will be ignored (without `[]`) in 1.1.5 version.

Comment: really? I'm on 1.1.5 , tried with the code [:userId] and doesn't ignore them.

Comment: try without `[]`. See this commit: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/53061363c7aa1ab9085273d269c6f04ac2162336

Comment: oops, sorry, it's about $resource, not sure if it will work in routing. excuse me.

Comment: If g-orge's answer is good, would you please mark it so that people don't have to scroll the whole thing to find the best answer?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

It looks like Angular has support for this now.

From the latest (v1.2.0) docs for [`$routeProvider.when(path, route)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#$routeProvider-methods):

`path` can contain optional named groups with a question mark (`:name?`)

Comment: Any way to avoid using the trailing slash?  If my route is: `.when('/claims/documents/:CLAIMS_ID/:DOCUMENT_NAME?'...` it won't match if the url doesn't have a trailing slash.  So `/claims/documents/1234/` matches, but `/claims/documents/1234` doesn't.

Comment: Would like to know if anyone has a solution for the problem reported by @JamesBell

Comment: As of Angular 1.3, the trailing slash issue mentioned in the above comments is fixed. Navigating to /claims/documents/1234/ works correctly, as does /claims/documents/1234. In short, it works with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: I am still seeing this behavior if I have an optional parameter in my route.  For example: if the route is: '/:classification?/package/compare'  and I try to navigate to the url "/package/compare" it works.  If I try '/package/compare/' for some reason I get the asci code appended to the classification, or '/%3f/package/compare' which isn't an actual route.

Comment: Documentation is confusing.

Answer (score 60):

Like @g-eorge mention, you can make it like this:

```
module.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/users/:userId?', {templateUrl: 'template.tpl.html', controller: myCtrl})
}]);
```

You can also make as much as u need optional parameters.

Answer (score 8):

Please see @jlareau answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534710/angularjs-how-to-use-routeparams-in-generating-the-templateurl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817458/41621)

You can use a function to generate the template string:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {templateUrl:'/home'}).
            when('/users/:user_id', 
                {   
                    controller:UserView, 
                    templateUrl: function(params){ return '/users/view/' + params.user_id;   }
                }
            ).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think OZ_ may be somewhat correct.

If you have the route `'/users/:userId'` and navigate to `'/users/'` (note the trailing /), `$routeParams` in your controller should be an object containing `userId: ""` in 1.1.5. So no the paramater `userId` isn't completely ignored, but I think it's the best you're going to get.