# AngularJS: Can angularJS route parameters be assigned to multiple values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Assume the following route provider:

```
    myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {        

    $routeProvider.when('/multivalues/:value/:value/:value',
    {templateUrl: 'partials/multivalues.html',
    controller: 'MultiValueController'});
}]);
```

Ideally, we would like the variable $routeParams.value to contain a list of 3 elements. It seems that angularJS does not support this functionality.

What is the best practice to implement this functionality?

Comment: I'm afraid it can't contain 3 elements. You should use different var names:
'/multivalues/:value1/:value2/:value3'

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: I would like to pass values in a route dynamically, i.e., "/multivalues/:value1/:value2/.../:value10" for passing 10 values.

However, the number of different values might be less than ten. Of course, I do not want to write explicitly all the different routes from 1 to 10 ("/multivalues/:values1", "/multivalues/:values1/:values2", etc).

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, under what situation will you need to pass a varying number of params?

Comment: Have you considered something like `/:value` then using `$routeParams.value.split('&&')`?

Comment: @MorganDelaney Thanks Morgan. Yes, this is one approach.

I have just realized that it is possible to have optional route parameters which might be well suited for my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510962/can-angularjs-routes-have-optional-parameter-values