# angular ngRoute optional paths

Tags: angularjs, url-routing, ngroute

I have the following routes that I'd like to match

```
/biblioteca
/biblioteca/whatever
```

So far now I made two routes, like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/biblioteca', { ...
$routeProvider.when('/biblioteca/:path*', { ...
```

Is there some way to capture both of them with a single route, stating that the :path* part is optional? perhaps something like...

```
$routeProvider.when('/biblioteca/:?path*', { ...
```

what would be the correct way to handle such a case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510962/can-angularjs-routes-have-optional-parameter-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the question mark after the named group.

```
$routeProvider.when('/biblioteca/:path?', { ...
```

> - path can contain optional named groups with a question mark: e.g.:name?.

See [docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)