# Extra character while using multiple optional parameter in angular route

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using angularjs router, as the application development is almost done, **I cant use UI-router**. Recently I implemented two optional parameter in route by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19224769/2034794) answer.
Here is what I did.

```
app.when('/someUrl/:param1?/:param2?',{
   templateUrl:'templateurl',
   controller:'controllerName'
});
```

But when I use `$location.path('/someUrl/1234/5678');`, the url is adding equivalent hex code of '?' in URL either parameter is available or not.

I am not sure why this parameter is coming even if I am sending parameter.
the url is looking like

```
localhost/someurl/1234%3F/5638%3F
```

How can avoid this %3F and keep optional routing functionality without using duplicate route definitions.

**Sorry for typo mistake, I already defined routes with :, that is not problem with `:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%3F` is `?`, Since you have not provided the `:` its treated as part of URL thus they are encoded.

You need to use `:` to define parameter.

```
app.when('/someUrl/:param1?/:param2?',{
   templateUrl:'templateurl',
   controller:'controllerName'
});
```

Comment: this is not the problem with ':'. I updated my question, by mistake, I forget to mention ':' here in question. Colon is not  the problem.

Comment: It is taking the parameters but with '?', I can access parameters with param variable, and the value is included with '?' character

Comment: @LaxmikantDange, Which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: @LaxmikantDange, There should not be any problem

Comment: yes there is, is adding extra '?' character as mentioned in optional parameter declaration. if I doesnt pass any parameter then also it is including '?' as parameter