# AngularJS optional route parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularJS application where the route can be one of the below

```
www.website.com/blog/xyz
www.website.com/blog/xyz/title/other-params
```

In last url, title parameter is use for user readability sake, so it's not compulsory in the url. Hence I am using below angularJS code for my route.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/blog', {
        templateUrl : url,
        controller : 'blogsHome'
    })
    .when('/blog/:blog_id', {
        templateUrl : url,
        controller : 'blogInfo'
    })
    .when('/blog/:blog_id/:url_params*', {
        templateUrl : url,
        controller : 'blogInfo'
    });
```

Now, in above code, I had to add *middle* **when** because angular expect `:url_params` and can not be empty. Is there any way I can omit *middle* **when** statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can angularjs routes have optional parameter values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510962/can-angularjs-routes-have-optional-parameter-values)

Comment: @dxcorzo Yeah but it does not work with *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `*` to you work with ***multiple levels of directories*** dynamically and adding `?` to work with optional path. But when you want work with **multiple levels** but **optional** then  can try like this `?:multipleOptionalParams*?`

so try this one:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'blog.html',
        controller : 'myCtrl'
    })
    .when('/blog/:blog_id/?:url_params*?', {
        templateUrl : 'details.html',
        controller : 'details'
    });
```

Can visit [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qx3xBHxReedSw68ud22Q?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to replace the 3rd when with the second one to change the sequence which when matches first.

Like so, the most complicated first:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/blog', {
        templateUrl : url,
        controller : 'blogsHome'
    })
    .when('/blog/:blog_id/:url_params*', {
        templateUrl : url,
        controller : 'blogInfo'
    })
    .when('/blog/:blog_id', {
        templateUrl : url,
        controller : 'blogInfo'
    });
```