# How to track my campaign when the landing page has been implemented in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url, builder

I would like to ask you, If i want to track my campaign using utm parametrs, is it possible when the url contains the hashmrk # ?

My url is just like this https://www.example.com/#/start, can i put parameters on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "track my campaign"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can angularjs routes have optional parameter values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510962/can-angularjs-routes-have-optional-parameter-values)

Answer (score 0):

you can mention in your app.js

```
.state('abc.campaign-timeline', {
            url: '/campaign-timeline?campaign',
            templateUrl: 'views/abc/campaign-timeline.html',
            controller: 'campaignTimeline',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            params: {
                 'campaign': 'campaign.campaignId'
             }

        })
```

and while calling

```
$state.go('klient.campaign-timeline',   {'campaign':"67});
```

so in your url will be line this `localhost://abc.com/abc/campaign-timeline?campaign=67`