# AngularJS dynamic parameters count in $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on my first Angular app and it's really cool.

I have some trouble to work with routers

I have some routings:

```
.when("/products/:productcat", { templateUrl : "/home/config", controller : "configController" })
.when("/products/:productcat/:nx/:nxvalue", { templateUrl : "/home/config", controller : "configController" })
```

I have a configurator, and I wont to pass more parameters as I can define in rountig provider.  I illustrated to steps of configurating a product, but there are about 7-20 steps. Whats is the best way to handle it?

What I mean looks like this:

```
.when("/products/:productcat/:nx/:nxvalue", { templateUrl : "/home/config", controller : "configController" })
.when("/products/:productcat/:nx/:nxvalue/:nx2/:nxvalue2", { templateUrl : "/home/config", controller : "configController" })
.when("/products/:productcat/:nx/:nxvalue/:nx2/:nxvalue2/:nx3/:nxvalue3", { templateUrl : "/home/config", controller : "configController" })
```

But I cant create about 30 routs and check each time are all parameters set or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524533/can-angularjs-routes-have-default-parameter-values

Comment: Think whether they have be part of querystring or url. Url is more of parent->child->child format, but if they are just parameters querystring can be used.

Comment: any reply? i too have same issue

Comment: @kans unfortunately not, I have just make a list of 20 params and check is there set or not.