# Default route for angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The sample demo of the angular ui router has this link for the start page:

full url of 'ui-router' is `/` or  `http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/`

full url of 'about' is `/about` or `http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/about`

When I was using durandalJS there was a limitation that the default url is just "/" there can be no "/ui-router".

Has the angular ui router plugin the same limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) there is an "otherwise" option for a default route.

If you are talking about default route PARAMETERS, then there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524533/can-angularjs-routes-have-default-parameter-values).

Comment: @apohi: ui-router != angular-route.

Comment: Why was this answer chosen? angular router(ngRoute) is different from angular ui router(ui.router). This might confuse the beginners.

Comment: @boi_echos I'm a beginner, but from what I see in this answer it looks correct. UI-Router has an `otherwise` function. Can you point out what is incorrect?

Comment: I fixed the first link.

Comment: @hofnarwillie This answer says that `otherwise` is an option (e.g., a property passed in on an object) instead of a function.

Comment: This answer links to things and does not include enough of a description or example to be useful on its own.

Answer (score 18):

The default route for ui-router can be whatever you want it to be, there is no limitaion like in DurandalJS. Just use:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("otherwise", { url : '/otherwise'...})
```

This is the official documentaion of ui-router, however I could not find the otherwise technique in there: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

@apohi: ui-router is not angular-route. Your reply is adressing the wrong module.

Comment: The OP was asking about ui-router, your first link points to documentation on angular-router.

Comment: Otherwise should be a function call on `$urlRouterProvider`, not the name passed to `.state()`—unless you intend to set `url: '/otherwise'` on your default route…

Answer (score 7):

You can do it this way:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router']).config([
  '$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
     $stateProvider.state('default', {
     controller: 'MyController',
     templateUrl: 'path/to/index.html',
     url:''
  })
)];
```

That way whenever the url is on the root of your site ui-router will capture it on a state that matches, in this case, 'default'.

Answer (score 5):

use the $urlRouterProvider and its otherwise function:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider.state('default', {
     controller: 'MyController',
     templateUrl: 'path/to/template.ng.html',
     url:'/default'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/default')
  })];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $urlRouterProvide.otherwise. This will work if you try to navigate to a route url that has not been defined.

Taken from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/89).

```
function configurUIRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('myhomepage',
    {
        abstract: false,
        url: '/myhomepageurl',
        templateUrl: "some-path/staff-admin.html",
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/myhomepageurl'); // User will be taken to /myhomepageurl if they enter a non-matched entry into URL

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way of all**

> add **$urlRouterProvider** service in **config(function($urlRouterProvider))**

and then

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('employeesState'); //default route

         $stateProvider.state('employeesState', function(){
              //state configuration here
         }) //employees state

         $stateProvider.state('cutomersState', function(){
             //state configuration here
         })
}
```

name any of the state in otherwise function to which you want as your default state/route