# How to initialize default route in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to use angular routing in my application. The problem is that the route "/" does not get initialized automatically. So I first go to "/" and the main content of the page is empty (the template is not loaded at all), I click the link to /settings and settings are loaded, then I click a link to "/" and this time the template is initialized correctly. So how do I make the thing initialized at the beginning?

Here's my routing configuration:

```
 app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
          }).when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: '/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
          }).when('/settings', {
            templateUrl: '/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsController'
          });

          $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
          });
        });
```

I tried calling $location.url("/profile") from a controller and it did help, but the url has to be changed and I would rather keep the "/"

Comment: Try removing the trailing commas in your .when()'s for a start

Comment: doesn't help. Also, as far as I know it is perfectly okay to have a trailing comma in your property listing in JS

Comment: In some cases it can break things. So you shouldn't leave trailing commas just for the sake of it. It was merely a pointer rather than an answer :)

Comment: have you try to read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12807157/3033318)

Answer (score 1):

use  `otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" })`

**Update : here how it should be**

```
 $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
          }).when('/profile', {
            templateUrl: '/profile.html',
            controller: 'ProfileController',
          }).when('/settings', {
            templateUrl: '/settings.html',
            controller: 'SettingsController'
          }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

Comment: looks like something I should add to my code anyway, but doesn't really solve this particular problem :(

Comment: I did a dirty hack... first I configured the "otherwise" and then I did the $location.url("/whatever"). Now the page is initialized nicely :P

Comment: just remove "/" from all your templateURL

Comment: doesn't help. I'm gonna stick to my solution inspired by your original advice :)