# Default value for parameters in state.go angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have make route in my `app.js`, well I need receive two parameters in `upsr` URL.

```
.state('upsr', {
   url: '/upsr/:QuestionIdIndex/:LangId',
   templateUrl: 'modules/study/question/question-details.html',
   controller: 'upsrCtrl'
})
```

How I can use `$state.go` without sending any parameters like below?

```
$state.go('upsr');
```

Instead of:

```
$state.go('upsr',{
    QuestionIdIndex : 0,
    LangId:0
});
```

Note: If there were no any parameters, then it will set as default value. For example

```
QuestionIdIndex = 0; 
LangId = 0;
```

My problems was if I just use `$state.go('upsr');` then it would be error.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: $state.go('upsr', { 'QuestionIdIndex ':'0', 'LangId ':0' });

Comment: I knew that..I just want to use `$state.go('upsr')` for default instead of ` 
$state.go('upsr', { 'QuestionIdIndex ':'0', 'LangId ':0' }); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `params` option when defining your state.

> **Note:** optional parameters requires [angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-beta.3/angular-ui-router.js) so then it will match with `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/upsr');`

```
.state('upsr', {
   url: '/upsr/{QuestionIdIndex}/{LangId}',
   params: {
      QuestionIdIndex: { value: 0 },
      LangId: { value: 0 }
   },
   templateUrl: 'modules/study/question/question-details.html',
   controller: 'upsrCtrl'
})
```

Comment: Also can be implement in
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/upsr')`?

Comment: @Imran maybe, which version you are using?

Comment: How do I check?

Comment: you can see on the header of `angular-ui-router.js`

Comment: @Imran newer versions of ui-router implements optional parameters, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to make them as [optional parameters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider),

```
state('upsr', {
   url: '/upsr/:QuestionIdIndex?/:LangId?',
   templateUrl: 'modules/study/question/question-details.html',
   controller: 'upsrCtrl'
})
```

Comment: Also can be implement in
`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/upsr')`?

Comment: @Imran yes you can

Comment: How to set default value for `QuestionIdIndex` and `LangId`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524533/can-angularjs-routes-have-default-parameter-values